# php ini_set expose_php

Tags: php

I am trying to get expose_php to off with ini_set, except it seems to not be working. I tried the value 0, and Off, but neither work.

```
ini_set('expose_php',0);
```

help?

Comment: Uh... `expose_php` or `display_errors`?

Comment: whoops lol copied wrong line, expose_php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

It can only be set in php.ini.

Answer (score 14):

If you are on PHP >= 5.3.0:

```
header_remove('X-Powered-By');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

Or on an older version:

```
header('X-Powered-By: ');
```

(This will hide PHP and the version, but the "X-Powered-By" string will still be visible in the header.)

However the PHP version might still be visible in the "Server: " part of the header. So this isn't bulletproof.

Comment: Server header can be removed through: `header_remove('Server');`. I edited the answer to include this!

Answer (score 7):

Overwrite the header:

```
header('X-Powered-By: ');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ini_set('display_errors','0');
```

Both parameters need to be strings, as I recall. Try that.